# image couldn't loaded from ios device in unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am using unity to load facebook profile picture that saved in device. The code is working fine in Android but not IOS. I was suffering this problem for many days. So here is my code, please help me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UserProfilePicture : MonoBehaviour {
public RawImage profilePicture, testProfile;
private Texture2D texture,text;



void FixedUpdate(){
    if (FbSetup.userInfoLoaded) {
        if(SPFacebook.instance.userInfo.GetProfileImage(FacebookProfileImageSize.square) != null) {
            text = SPFacebook.instance.userInfo.GetProfileImage(FacebookProfileImageSize.square);
        }
    }

    testProfile.texture = text as Texture;

    byte[] textureByte = text.EncodeToPNG ();
    File.WriteAllBytes (Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"profilePicture.png"),textureByte);

    Debug.Log("Save path: " + Application.persistentDataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "profilePicture.png");

    if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "profilePicture.png")){
        Debug.Log("Texture saved");
    }

}

void Update(){
    StartCoroutine (Control ());
    profilePicture.texture = texture as Texture;
}


IEnumerator Control(){
    WWW pictureUrl;
    pictureUrl = new WWW(System.Uri.EscapeUriString("file://" + Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"profilePicture.png")));

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    texture = pictureUrl.texture;

    Debug.Log("Loaded path: " + Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"profilePicture.png"));
}


void OnEnable(){
    if (GLobal.playAsGuest) {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else{
        this.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Appreciate for your help, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `"file://" + Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"profilePicture.png"` is right?

Comment: ya, it is working on android.
It this script no working on ios?

Comment: I mean, AFAIK, this path should not work on iOS. Try without `file://` part.

Comment: Just tried, it is not working even on android.
It there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Hm. Let's clarify. Is the texture file created and just can not be read? Or is it even not created?

Comment: The texture file is created but can not be read so it showed a question mark on the profile picture.

Comment: Oh wait. I see `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();`. Try `yield return pictureUrl;`

Comment: it is working!!
Thanks, man!
May i know why WaitForEndOfFrame() is not working?

Comment: because it couldn't be completed within one frame :D Let me then write an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem is with following line.

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

Obviously, one frame is not enough to load the file from disk. You are lucky that it was enough on your android device. So you should change that line to

```
yield return pictureUrl;
```

So it will wait until it's done loading.

Comment: ah...i see
Thanks, my friend.
Really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're always welcome. BTW, if the answer solves your problem you should 'accept' it by clicking on arrow on the left side of the answer.

Comment: oh, alright~
sorry, i am new to this forum.
Thanks!

Comment: Ha, that's OK :D Have a nice experience from SO.